# Tests Internal Method raise null reference exception using XUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I am trying to setup a return for inner method of object `Parameter` but the setup of the `SetObject` throws a nullreference exception so far I am not sure what causing it.
Knowing `_parameterManager` is mocked object using `moq`, see the code below:

```
 _parameterManager.Setup(x => x.Parameters)
    .Returns(new System.Collections.Generic.List<IParameter>()
    {
        new Parameter()
        {
            Description = new ParameterDescriptor()
            {
                ParameterId = new ParameterId()
                {
                    Id = ParametersId.FERTILIZER_SELECTION_ID, ControllerIndex = 0
                },
            }
        },
        new Parameter()
        {
            Description = new ParameterDescriptor()
            {
                ParameterId = new ParameterId()
                {
                    Id = ParametersId.FERTILIZER_1_ID,ControllerIndex = 1
                },
            }   
        },
        new Parameter()
        {
            Description = new ParameterDescriptor()
            {
                ParameterId = new ParameterId()
                {
                    Id = ParametersId.FERTILIZER_2_ID,ControllerIndex = 2
                },
            }
        },   
        new Parameter()
        {
            Description = new ParameterDescriptor()
            {
                ParameterId = new ParameterId()
                {
                    Id = ParametersId.FERTILIZER_3_ID,ControllerIndex = 3
                },
            }
        },
    });

_parameterManager.Setup(x => x.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Description.ParameterId.Id == ParametersId.FERTILIZER_SELECTION_ID)
    .SetObject(It.IsNotNull<uint>()))
    .Returns(ParameterResult.Success);
```

Comment: Right-click your test in the Test Explorer, and click Debug. Your debugger should break when the exception occurs (if not, Check "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" in Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings)

Comment: it's checked but still dont know why its failing since the exception doesnt give any details.

Comment: You can see what line it's being raised on though...

Comment: That i know like I've mentioned " the setup of the SetObject throws a nullreference exception"

Comment: It's likely that `FirstOrDefault` doesn't find any matching elements, then

Comment: I will write an answer right away

Answer (score 1):

It was actually the `Parameter` inside the Collection that was a concrete object hence xunit couldn't mock the `SetObject` method, resulting in raising the mentioned exception.

The answer is either adding Mock `parameter` objects instead of concrete objects or fill up the parameter object fully.